# inheritance namespace javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

How can I inherit an objects variables within namespace(scope)?

```
var f2 = {
   a: 'test'
}

f2.history = {

  load: function(){ alert(this.a); }

}

// Turns out Undefined
f2.history.load();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no link between `f2.history` and `f2`. More generally there is no link between a property value and its holder.

You could call it like this :

```
f2.history.load.call(f2);
```

Or you could declare your objects with a factory :

```
var f2 = (function(){
    var self = {
        a: 'test'
    };
    self.history = {
        load: function(){ alert(self.a); }
    };
    return self;
})();
```

This would allow

```
f2.history.load();
```

Another variant would let you define the submodules in a more separated way :

```
var f2 = {
    a: 'test'
};
(function(f){
    f.history = {
        load: function(){ alert(f.a); }
    }
})(f2);
```

The advantage of this last construct is that it's easy to declare sub-modules in different files.

Comment: Seams really complicated, could I just use the prototype chain somehow?

Comment: @AdrianMcCool: You could make `f2.history` inherit from `f2`, but that hardly makes any sense to me

Comment: Modules/submodules and inheritance are very different concepts. Inheritances makes little sense without instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

use the namespace, f2, not `this`.

```
 load: function(){ alert(f2.a); }
```

works

---

```
var f2 = {
    a : 'test',
    init: function(a) {
        if (a) this.a = a; //set a, if a is defined
    },
};
function history(a) {
    function F() {};
    F.prototype = f2;
    var f = new F();
    f.init(a);
    load = function() {
        alert(f.a);
    }
    return this;
}

var h1 = history();
h1.load(); //alerts "test"

var h2 = history('history'); 
h2.load(); //alerts "history"

//but now h1 also holds history
h1.load();
```

Comment: OK. But why would you want to "override" an object literal? There is only one f2 (example)